# How can I specify the size and position of a selection in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5

I'm wondering if I could specify the size and position accurately by input the width and height and the x-y coordinates of the rectangular or ellipse selection. I want to have a very small selected region but it seems hard to obtain by moving mouse manually. As for the wanted position, I can move the selection region using the <kbd>Up</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the rectangular and elliptical marquee tools you can specify the size by setting the `Fixed size` style.

[image: Photoshop selection marquee styles]

Then you can use the mouse and/or keyboard arrow keys to position the selection.

Comment: thanx so much :)